# How can I add borders between floating <div> elements depending on where the floating <div> lands?

Tags: html, css

I have products on a website with borders between them, but no borders at the top, bottom, left and right.

It's something like this:

```
a | b | c | d
--------------
e | f | g | h
--------------
j | k | l | m
```

where | and - are borders
The letters from a to m are product images and texts inside `<div>` elements.

Right now I'm using nth-child(4), nth-child(8), etc. to remove the right borders from the products and something similar for the top, left and bottom borders, which works for the 4x4 rows and columns I have at the moment. But I want to have the option of increasing the number of rows or have infinite scrolling without having to change the css styling.

What would be the best approach for that?

Comment: You can use class like "no-border-top" or / and "no-border-left" for exemple and add class on your html

Comment: This may be achievable with CSS Grid, using the grid-gap of 1px (as thick as your border should be), and then changing the container's background coor (the color of what your border would be). I will try to make a codepen in the answer below in one moment...

Comment: Will you always have 4 columns?

Comment: If you always have 4 columns you can use nth-child(4n) to target every fourth element. And you can do something similar for the other edges.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at my codepen and see if it helps. [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/akinhwan/pen/ypxrXo)

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 1px;
```

I am using CSS Grid to define the table of "products". This is a very flexible approach, basically there is no border, however the background-color of the container which is underneath each cell is peeking through the grid-gaps.
The top, right, bottom , left outer edges do not have a gray border. This can be manipulated with margin or padding on the container/cells.

Depending on the actual implementation on your product site, you may have this nested in another container. Feel free to comment and I can try to clarify.

Here is a link to caniuse for cross browser support info [caniuse: CSS Grid Layout](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

And ofcourse the official Mozilla Developer Network Doc on "grid" [MDN CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Comment: This is definitely a possible solution and it scales well. I would suggest linking to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It does also have [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), so depending on if OP needs to support IE browsers, they might need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Noted, I edited my answer to include some extra links.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the left and top borders by setting borders on the right and bottom only:

```
.container div {
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
```

To hide the right-most and bottom-most borders, set overflow to hidden on the container, and move the container's children down and to the right by the thickness of the border:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  transform: translate(1px, 1px);
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2em;
}

.container div {
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
  <div>e</div>
  <div>f</div>
  <div>g</div>
  <div>h</div>
  <div>j</div>
  <div>k</div>
  <div>l</div>
  <div>m</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of `:nth-child` selector.

First set `border-right` and `border-top` to every div.

Then using the `:nth-child(-n+4)` i.e. **(1, 2, 3, 4)** remove `border-top` of first four elements and `:nth-child(4n)` i.e. **(4, 8, 12, 16, etc.)** remove `border-right` of every 4th element of row.

> **Reference Link  *[nth-child CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)***

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(-n+4) {
  border-top: 0;
}

div:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
  <div>e</div>
  <div>f</div>
  <div>g</div>
  <div>h</div>
  <div>i</div>
  <div>j</div>
  <div>k</div>
  <div>l</div>
  <div>m</div>
  <div>n</div>
  <div>o</div>
  <div>p</div>
</main>
```

Comment: You might point out that this assumes there will be 4 items on the last row.  If there are fewer than 4, one or more items on the next-to-last row will be missing a bottom border.